# How do I Identify by row id the values in a data frame column not in another data frame column?

Tags: r

How do I identify by row id the values in data frame `d2` column `c3` that are not in data frame `d1` column `c1`? My which function returns all records when sub-setting as shown. My requirement is to follow this sub set structure and not `value$field` design which works:

```
c1 <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
c2 <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")

c3 <- c("A", "z", "C", "z", "E", "F")
c4 <- c("a", "x", "x", "d", "e", "f")

d1 <- data.frame(c1, c2, stringsAsFactors = F)
d2 <- data.frame(c3, c4, stringsAsFactors = F)

x <- unique(d1["c1"])
y <- d2[,"c3"]

id <- which(!(y %in% x) )  # incorrect, all row ids returned
```

I am trying to find the id's of rows in y where the specified column does not include values of x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `setdiff` would work here. I see `z` and `F` are what you want, right? They are not in `d1[,"c1"]` but are in `d2[,"c3"]`

```
includes <- setdiff(d2[,"c3"], d1[,"c1"])

d2_new <- d2[d2[,"c3"] %in% includes,]

d2_new$id <- rownames(d2_new)
d2_new

# or 

ids <- rownames(d2[d2[,"c3"] %in% includes,])
```

output

```
d2_new

#  c3 c4 id
#2  z  x  2
#4  z  d  4
#6  F  f  6

ids
#[1] "2" "4" "6"
```

Comment: good idea, now I just need to get the id's 2, 4 and 6?

Comment: In the sample data I don’t see any numeric values or id variable, could you clarify? I’ll modify my answer to be more accurate. Do you need row numbers?

Comment: the id's are just assigned as row indices automatically in the data frame at initiation

Comment: Does the edit solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and this code worked for me. However, indexing did not work for me. With a slight change it worked perfect.

```
includes <- setdiff(d2$c3, d1$c3)

d2_new <- d2[d2$c3 %in% includes,]

d2_new$id <- rownames(d2_new)
d2_new
```

thank you @jpsmith